# How to install Flask-SQLAlchemy from PyCharm terminal?

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm

I am using PyCharm with Python 3.8 and Flask. I downloaded Flask-SQLAlchemy on PyCharm terminal:

```
pip install  flask_sqlalchemy
```

Event log said installation successful. But when I write:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

It reports:

> unresolved reference flask_sqlalchemy

How to solve this?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

main = Flask(__name__)
main.config['SQlALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(main)

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %r>' % self.id
```

Comment: Which Python interpreter are you using in Pycharm? (Preferences -> Python interpreter), it's possible when you used the terminal you downloaded it for a different Python interpreter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.